# track outbound email from apex class

Tags: trigger, singleemailmessage, workflowoutboundmessage, activityhistory

I have a lookup from `Case` to `Lead`. Whenever a new `Case` is created if the contact field is not filled for the record , it sends an auto response mail to the corresponding Lead. I did this using trigger. How can I track the email in the activity history of the respective case?

Comment: case auto response rule works fine, but it sends the response message only to contact, not to lead

Comment: If you are sending the email using a trigger, then you should be able to create an Activity record for the case using the trigger as well.  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: from what I understand from my part of research on this is that Activity history is read-only. To solve the issue, I had to make a visual force page and add it to the case layout

Answer (score 0):

I made a Visualforce page that uses the standard controller tag referencing the case object and added the page to the case layout. this was fine enough.